# Checking number prefix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

I have some trouble in my script.

I am currently using:

```
 awk '{anum=substr($1,3,22); sub(/^0+/, "", anum); print anum}' file1 | grep -nf file2 | cut -d: -f1 | awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};FNR in a' - file1
```

file1

```
 5000000000009855892590xxxx xxx
 5000000000000068582654xxxx xxx
 5000000000009855892580xxxx xxx
 5000000000000765432100xxxx xxx
```

file2

```
 9855892588
 985589259
 8265
 76543210
```

I am getting the output using the two files below (file1 and file2):

```
 5000000000009855892590xxxx xxx
 5000000000000068582654xxxx xxx
 5000000000000765432100xxxx xxx
```

But my **expected output** is just:

```
5000000000009855892590xxxx xxx
5000000000000765432100xxxx xxx
```

My problem is that it captures **8265** in the middle of **5000000000000068582654xxxx** which is wrong. What else can I use in replacement of grep -nf to meet my condition? Should the numbers in file2 match the prefix or whole number of 3rd to 22nd digit of file1 (w/o leading zeros).

Comment: Why does `9765432100` match when it has a leading 9 ?

Comment: My bad. already updated my question

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any consistency to first file, how doe you decide which numbers are allowed and not ?

Comment: Just wanted to check if this **985589259** (file2) matches OR is PREFIX of **9855892590**  (file1)

Comment: Yes but the `765432100` has another leading 0 than that line

Comment: `awk '{anum=substr($1,3,22); sub(/^0+/, "", anum); print anum}' file1**` removes leading 0, doesn't matter how many leading 0 are. For  765432100(file1) and 76543210 (file2), the condition I've mentioned was also applied to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for your example but as I'm not really sure of exactly how you determine whats valid or not it may not be very robust.

```
gawk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}{match($0,/0+([1-9][0-9]+)0/,b)}a[b[1]]' file{2,1}

 5000000000009855892590xxxx xxx
 5000000000000765432100xxxx xxx
```

It creates an array of all the first fields in the first file(file2), then matches a string that i have guessed is your valid string, in the second file. Next if the string has been saved in the array it prints the line.

Not gawk version

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}{n=substr($1,3,22);sub(/^0+/, "", n)
     for(i in a)if(n~"^"a[i])print}' test2 test
```

Same start as the other, then remove the start of the line as OP has done, next for each saved element, check if the newly created line starts with it.

Comment: @newbie, in what way? Imagine someone saying that to you, is there any way i could possibly know what the problem is from your comment ?

Comment: I meant gawk is not supported, not installed in my OS, sorry for confusing you

Comment: it works! Thank you! Btw, can you explain to me further the `if(n~"^"a[i])`?

Comment: @newbie if `n`(the truncated line) `~`(contains) `"^"`(start of the line) `a[i]`(whatever is contained in `a[i]`. So ti just checks the line starts with the value of the element in  `a[i]`.